# How to position element in the top right corner using CSS inset?

Tags: html, css

Instead of the `top` and `right` CSS properties, I'd like to use  [`inset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) to position the element.

For example, the following code places the element to the top right corner:

```css
.top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

How would you achieve the same using the `inset` property? I have tried using different ways and can't figure it out.

Although I set both `top` and `right` to 0 with `inset` in the following example, it doesn't work:

```css
.top-right {
  inset: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset to clear the question :)

Answer (score 7):

It would be:

```css
.top-right {
  inset: 0 0 auto auto;
}
```

The order is top, right, bottom, left. It has the same multi-value syntax as the `margin` or the `padding` shorthand.

If you use `inset: 0 0;`, it's the same as `inset: 0 0 0 0;` and it means you also set the `bottom` and the `left` properties to 0. You could set them to the initial value (`auto`) instead to solve your problem.

Comment: @Jayg713 Mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark

Answer (score -1):

may be you changed position prop, so it takes default value that it static so when you use top, left, right and bottom aren't affected, and also inset prop

so to solve the problem change position to relative
live that code

```css
.container{
            position: relative;
            inset: 100px 100px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">hello world! </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your code sets the `bottom` and the `left` properties too. Check my answer for the solution.

Comment: thank for you, i know that but i want to Draw attention about change position prop before set inset prop